# Incidence rate ratios (Stata vs R)

Tags: r, stata, epidemiology, incidence-rate-ratio

I asked this question on Stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142118/incidence-rate-ratios-in-r-poisson-regression
 and was advised to post here instead.
I have data that looks like this

```
   sex agecat  cases population

1 male    0-4  12     126526
2 male    5-9  12     128375
3 female  0-4  11     129280
4 male    10-14 4     127910
5 female  0-4  13     127158
6 male    0-4  8      125125
```

I want to duplicate the output I get in stata with this command

```
poisson cases i.agecat, exp(pop) irr
```

which gives output such as:

```
   cases |        IRR   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  agecat |
      2  |   .5125755   .0530442    -6.18   0.000     .4578054    .6669639
      3  |    .323456   .0381304    -9.60   0.000     .2665044    .4172274
population | (exposure)
```

in R with a command such as

```
glm(cases~agecat, family = poisson(link = "log")
```

I know I need to exponentiate the coefficients and confidence intervals, but I think I also need some kind of offset so so that the intercept is zero; and adjust for per unit population vs baseline.

Can anyone help/advise ?

Thanks
EDIT: The question on SO has been answered, but I posted more detail here. In particular, I think the issue has to do with adjusting for population size in stata with exp(pop) - and how to replicate this in R.

Comment: Does removing the intercept from the model with `- 1` help? `glm(cases ~ agecat - 1, family = poisson(link = "log")`

Comment: No, this just puts the estimate for the intercept to the estimate of the baseline effect of agecat. I think the intercept issue is a red herring actually. It seems that using the irr option in stata just suppresses the display of the intercept.

Comment: As Ben mentioned in SO, it would be much easier to help if you provided a reproducible example, along with your result from Stata and R.

Comment: Hi jthetzel, yes, understood. I'm making a small reproducible dataset. What is the best way to post it ? It's just 9 rows similar to the above data.

Comment: Great.  See: http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000

Comment: OK, hopefully this does it:structure(list(sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("male", "female"), class = "factor"), agecat = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0-4", "5-9", "10-14"
), class = "factor"), cases = c(12L, 16L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
3L, 4L), population = c(126326L, 113634L, 127683L, 117000L, 126000L, 
123091L, 104682L, 124027L, 107294L)), .Names = c("sex", "agecat", 
"cases", "population"), row.names = c("1", "11", "21", "31", 
"41", "51", "61", "71", "81"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: As mentioned, I'm trying to reproduce the output from the Stata command poisson cases i.agecat, irr exp(pop) which gives .5525755 for agecat#2 and .333456 for agecat#3 (similar to the output I posted in my original post above)

Comment: With `glm(cases~agecat, offset = log(population), data = dat, family = poisson(link = "log"))` I get IRRs of 0.38 and 0.42 for 5-9 and 10-14, respectively.

Comment: Without the offset: `glm(cases~agecat, data = dat, family = poisson(link = "log"))`, I get IRRS of 0.40 and 0.42 for 5-9 and 10-14, respectively. Could you try `poisson cases i.agecat, irr` in Stata to see if the discrepancy is due to differences in the offsets?

Comment: According to this thread: http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg116971.html , `offset = log(population)` should be the equivalent of Stata's `exp(population)`.

Comment: Thanks to all. I've resolved it now. The offset=log() did in fact give the right estimates. I was just (stupidly) distracted by the intercept term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stata option `exp(pop)` includes log(pop) as an offset term in the linear predictor, so the **R** equivalent should be `offset=log(pop)`.

Comment: I tried this already:glm(formula = cases ~ agecat,offset=log(population), family = poisson(link = "log")) but it doesn't give the correct result. The effect of exp(pop) on the stata model is very small, but the effect of offset=log(population) in the R model is huge (after exponentiation)

Comment: Adding `offset=log(population)` to the R model should make a big difference to the estimate of the constant, but little difference to the estimates of the other parameters, as the populations are all similar. If it makes a big difference to those as well, something's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at glm documentation? there is an offset() function that can be included.

```
glm(cases~agecat+offset(log(population)), family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

Comment: Yes, I tried offset=log(population) but it doesn't give the correct result.

Comment: @P Sellaz: It appears that @B_Miner's suggestion is for a function that goes in the glm formula, as opposed to an argument to glm. I'd guess they act the same, but perhaps not.

Comment: They seem to act the same